# IntelliJ show diff with local version on the left and remote version on the right

Tags: intellij-idea

When doing a diff between a local file and its remote version the local version is shown on the right, by default, as shown below.
[image]

Is there any setting that would allow me to change this behavior and have the local version on the left and the remote one on the right ?

Using IntelliJ Idea 2023.1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature. You can create a feature request on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) to implement that